# Tex.SE at the Joint Mathematics Meetings

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Two things about TeX.SE and the [Joint Mathematics Meetings](http://www.ams.org/meetings/national/jmm/2125_intro.html) in January in New Orleans.

1. Anyone else besides me going?  Interested in a meetup?
2. TUG often has an exhibitor's table.  It might be good to have something there that would promote the site.  Whether it's a flyer, a card, or some trinket.  Your thoughts on the feasibility of that?

Answer (score 4):

Promotion: if you are happy spending the time, it can only do us good.

The TCS site has been energetic in promoting their site, and one thing they did that might work here is [assembling a list of questions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/nominations-for-publicity-poster-at-focs) to put on a poster that shows off the value of the site.  Their bait is different they want to show that "Science You Don't Want To Miss Out On" is being done on their Q&A, but the poster idea might work here.